# Как отсортировать посты по дате?

Tags: laravel

Как поменять формат и отсортировать посты по дате? Сейчас дата отображается так: `2022-01-13 21:11:17`. Нужно убрать время, и оставить только дату

```
<table class="table">
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $post->id }} </th>

        <th><a href="{{ route('admin.post.show', ['post' => $post->id]) }}"> {{ $post->title }} </a></th>

        <th>
            @if ($post->published_by)
            <a href="{{ route('admin.post.published_by', ['post' => $post->id]) }}"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z" />
                    <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z" />
                </svg></a>

            @else
            <a href="{{ route('admin.post.published_by', ['post' => $post->id]) }}"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye-slash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M13.359 11.238C15.06 9.72 16 8 16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5a7.028 7.028 0 0 0-2.79.588l.77.771A5.944 5.944 0 0 1 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755-.165.165-.337.328-.517.486l.708.709z" />
                    <path d="M11.297 9.176a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.474-4.474l.823.823a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.829 2.829l.822.822zm-2.943 1.299.822.822a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.474-4.474l.823.823a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.829 2.829z" />
                    <path d="M3.35 5.47c-.18.16-.353.322-.518.487A13.134 13.134 0 0 0 1.172 8l.195.288c.335.48.83 1.12 1.465 1.755C4.121 11.332 5.881 12.5 8 12.5c.716 0 1.39-.133 2.02-.36l.77.772A7.029 7.029 0 0 1 8 13.5C3 13.5 0 8 0 8s.939-1.721 2.641-3.238l.708.709zm10.296 8.884-12-12 .708-.708 12 12-.708.708z" />
                </svg></a>
            @endif
        </th>

        <th><a href="{{ route('admin.post.edit', ['post' => $post->id]) }}"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pen" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="m13.498.795.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001zm-.644.766a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L1.95 11.756l-.764 3.057 3.057-.764L14.44 3.854a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-1.585-1.585z" />
                </svg></a></th>

        <th>
            <form action="{{ route('admin.post.destroy', ['post' => $post->id]) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="btn" type="submit"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash3-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1H6v-1Zm5 0v1h3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-.538l-.853 10.66A2 2 0 0 1 11.115 16h-6.23a2 2 0 0 1-1.994-1.84L2.038 3.5H1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 0h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11 1.5ZM4.5 5.029a.5.5 0 1 1 .998-.06l.5 8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.998.06l-.5-8.5Zm6.53-.528a.5.5 0 0 1 .47.528l-.5 8.5a.5.5 0 1 1-.998-.058l.5-8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .528-.47ZM8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Z" />
                    </svg></button>
            </form>
        </th>
        <th>{{ $post->created_at }}</th>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите сортировать прям в шаблоне, то можно как-то так сделать:

```
@foreach ($posts->sortBy('created_at') as $post)
  ...
  <th>{{ $post->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</th>
  ...
@endforeach
```

А вообще, лучше сортировку производить в контроллере, а формат даты задавать в моделе, например так:

```
public function getFormattedDateAttriubte()
{
   return $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

А в шаблоне используйте `$post->formatted_date`.

Comment: Спасибо. А почему лучше это делать в контроллере и модели? Если сделать через шаблон, все работает корректно

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сортировать в обратном порядке через `sortBy('created_at')`?

Comment: "А почему лучше это делать в контроллере и модели?" - это скорее рекомендация, как правильно оформлять код, чтобы с ним было удобнее работать. Ну и при запросе из контроллера можно организовать сортировку на уровне базы данных, а не приложения. Что-то типо такого: `$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at')->get();`

Comment: "Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сортировать в обратном порядке через sortBy('created_at')?" - 2 варианта: `sortBy('created_at', 'desc')` и `sortByDesc('created_at')`.